# Crear archivo en otro directorio que no es el actual (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero crear el archivo dentro de la carpeta de la línea 1 que se crea en el mismo nivel donde se crea el archivo.txt

```
os.mkdir(svnombreRP.get())
archi = open('%s.txt' % svnombreRP.get(), 'wb')
archi.close()
```

He intentado ponerlo así:

```
os.mkdir(svnombreRP.get())
archi = open('%s/%s.txt' % svnombreRP.get(), 'wb')
archi.close()
```

Ya que quiero que el archivo se llame igual que el directorio, el nombre se lo dá la función svnombreRP.get() pero no se guardarlo dentro del directorio, me lo guarda al lado del directorio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si no te he entendido mal, lo que quieres es que se cree una carpeta dentro del directorio donde se aloja tu script y dentro de esa carpeta se cree el `.txt`. El archivo y la carpeta tienen el mismo nombre (dado por `svnombreRP.get()`).

El uso del operador de cadenas `%`, si no recuerdo mal, fué marcado como `deprecated` en Python 3 y se supone que desaparecerá en un futuro. No se que versíón usas pero te recomiendo usar `str.format()` para este tipo de cosas (funciona en Python 2.7 y 3.x):

```
os.mkdir(svnombreRP.get())
archi = open('{0}/{0}.txt'.format(svnombreRP.get()), 'wb')
archi.close()
```

Esto debería funcionar. Por cierto, `mkdir()` producirá un error si el directorio ya existe, debes tenerlo en cuenta.

Comment: Una vez mas tu solución es la correcta. Gracias